# Configure Xubuntu session (not vanilla xfce) with XRDP

Tags: xubuntu, xrdp

sesman.ini

```
[SessionVariables]
PULSE_SCRIPT=/etc/xrdp/pulse/default.pa
GDMSESSION=xubuntu
DESKTOP_SESSION=xubuntu
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=xubuntu
```

startwm.ini

```
#!/bin/bash
# xrdp X session start script (c) 2015, 2017 mirabilos
# published under The MirOS Licence

# export GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=ubuntu
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE
export DESKTOP_SESSION=xubuntu
export XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=xubuntu

if test -r /etc/profile; then
    . /etc/profile
fi

if test -r /etc/default/locale; then
    . /etc/default/locale
    test -z "${LANG+x}" || export LANG
    test -z "${LANGUAGE+x}" || export LANGUAGE
    test -z "${LC_ADDRESS+x}" || export LC_ADDRESS
    test -z "${LC_ALL+x}" || export LC_ALL
    test -z "${LC_COLLATE+x}" || export LC_COLLATE
    test -z "${LC_CTYPE+x}" || export LC_CTYPE
    test -z "${LC_IDENTIFICATION+x}" || export LC_IDENTIFICATION
    test -z "${LC_MEASUREMENT+x}" || export LC_MEASUREMENT
    test -z "${LC_MESSAGES+x}" || export LC_MESSAGES
    test -z "${LC_MONETARY+x}" || export LC_MONETARY
    test -z "${LC_NAME+x}" || export LC_NAME
    test -z "${LC_NUMERIC+x}" || export LC_NUMERIC
    test -z "${LC_PAPER+x}" || export LC_PAPER
    test -z "${LC_TELEPHONE+x}" || export LC_TELEPHONE
    test -z "${LC_TIME+x}" || export LC_TIME
    test -z "${LOCPATH+x}" || export LOCPATH
fi

if test -r /etc/profile; then
    . /etc/profile
fi

dbus-update-activation-environment --verbose XDG_DATA_DIRS XDG_CONFIG_DIRS DESKTOP_SESSION GDMSESSION XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP

test -x /etc/X11/Xsession && exec /etc/X11/Xsession
exec /bin/sh /etc/X11/Xsession
```

The XRDP session does appear to start with an xubuntu session, however, the desktop backgrounds between a normal xubuntu session and the xrdp one are both different.

Could this be a difference in session settings altogether rather than XRDP starting as vanilla xfce?

edit:
I was not able to find in .config or in .local any config settings that pointed to a particular desktop background for xfce.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
SESSION_MANAGER=local/noorez-HPE-421f:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/31644,unix/noorez-HPE-421f:/tmp/.ICE-unix/31644
WINDOWID=60817411
QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-xubuntu:/etc/xdg:/etc/xdg
XDG_MENU_PREFIX=xfce-
CLUTTER_BACKEND=x11
LANGUAGE=en_CA:en
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
DESKTOP_SESSION=xubuntu
SSH_AGENT_PID=31752
GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge
PWD=/home/noorez
LOGNAME=noorez
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=xubuntu
QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk2
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
PULSE_SCRIPT=/etc/xrdp/pulse/default.pa
HOME=/home/noorez
LANG=en_CA.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=XFCE
VTE_VERSION=6003
XRDP_SOCKET_PATH=/run/xrdp/sockdir
XRDP_PULSE_SOURCE_SOCKET=xrdp_chansrv_audio_in_socket_11
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-256color
GTK_OVERLAY_SCROLLING=0
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
USER=noorez
XRDP_SESSION=1
DISPLAY=:11.0
XRDP_PULSE_SINK_SOCKET=xrdp_chansrv_audio_out_socket_11
SHLVL=1
XDG_SESSION_ID=c54
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/xfce4:/usr/share/xubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop:/usr/share
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/snap/bin
GDMSESSION=xubuntu
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
UID=1000
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/home/noorez/.config/dconf
```

Comment: Xubuntu 20.04 - sorry, I didn't quite follow what other details you requested.

Comment: FYI: 20.04 provides what was requested (it tells us most of the software stack in use (XFCE version etc... okay we don't know if you're using the GA or HWE lower level stacks, being the two choices available & chosen by the installation media utilized (or changed post-install though few do that), but your question relates to XFCE more than kernel & video stack in use)...  you answered you're using a GTK3 stack XFCE :)   the detail should be added to your question, not replied via comment